# WAP not recognizing LAN over a long (50 metre) ethernet cable

Tags: lan, ethernet, cable

here is the situation...I've got my main router in the basement, and want to install a WAP on the 1st floor so I can access the internet from my room.

So I ended up getting a WAP (of TPLink) and connecting it to the main router via a 50m CAT5 cable.

Now the issue is that when I connect the 50m end to the WAP, it does not detect the network..(when I connect the WAP through a shorter cable it detects the LAN and runs fine).

I connected the 50m cable to my laptop and it was working fine-but at 10Mbps. Also when I connect the 50m cable to my brother's computer it doesn't detect any network either.

Any ideas what could be the issue? Is there some limit on the length of cables on Ethernet I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a bad cable. Toss it and get a new one. 50m is not the problem, those cables are spec'd up to 100m. Most likely there is at least one broken pair, probably more inside the cable.

Comment: If you can't test it with a proper test device, toss it.  MarkM has the right idea.

Comment: Yea, changed wire and it worked :)